# lsblk vs lshw -class disk,DVD not recognized

Tags: hard-disk

I insert blank new DVD-R

```
lshw -class disk
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-cdrom                 
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       product: CDDVDW SH-222AB
       vendor: TSSTcorp
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/cdrw
       logical name: /dev/dvd
       logical name: /dev/dvdrw
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: SB00
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=ready
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/cdrom
```

On the other side

```
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk 
sda      8:0    0 111,8G  0 disk 
├─sda2   8:2    0 103,4G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
```

I don't understand why my DVD is not recognized by `lsblk`? Also why is physical id 0, what is the meaning of 0 in this case?

Comment: Do you have some medium inserted in your DVD drive?

Comment: @don_crissti Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @JaroslavKucera Blank DVD,bought today.

Comment: Try to put some DVD with data on it in and see then.